# Parse user.signUp, error call back not triggered

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using parse javascript SDK, but when I try to handle user registration errors, such like username already taken, the error callback is not triggered.
The code I have is:

```
        signUp: function () {
            var self = this;
            var errors = this.form.commit({ validate: true });
            if(errors) return;
            mainapp.showSpinner();
            this.model.signUp({
                success: function (user) {
                    console.log(user);
                },
                error: function (user, error) {
                    //mainapp.hideSpinner();
                    console.log('called')
                    self.errorMessage.html(error);
                }
            });
        },
```

And the `console.log('called)` is not triggered, but in console of Chrome I have an javascript error `POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request)`

Any idea how can i catch and handle the error in the error callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking at the Parse JS sdk documentation, it seems like you miss one parameter when calling sign up function :

```
user.signUp(null, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-signing-up

Hope this could help to solve your problem.